# Make header view unchanged when switch to another tab

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UITabBarController. Now I want to add a view above it, and make the view unchanged when users switch to another tab. I've tried to create a UIViewController, and add the UITabBarController as a subview, but it crashed when I switched to another tab.

Is there any good way to do it? Thanks for any help.

[image: What my app will look like]

Comment: What was the exception message when the app crashed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is. What you'll want to do is make a view controller, which will house the view that is constantly visible, and add the tab bar controller on top of it. If you're using storyboards, this can be accomplished easily using a container view. Simply drag and drop a container from the object library onto the view controller you created, size it as you wish, and link its viewDidLoad segue to embed on the tab bar controller.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/91385349/tabInView.zip

Comment: It's so simple. Thank you very much. By the way, what's the oldest iOS version I can use "Container View"? I think that it use addChildViewController to complete the job, so iOS should >= 5, am I right?

Comment: @iForests I believe so, I'm looking through the UIViewController class reference and I'm having a hard time finding evidence to the contrary.